# Separate dates between two dates

Tags: entity-framework, webforms

I have a table that stores my sold products and this table has a column that stores date of bought.

For example :

```
01/01/2015  200$
02/01/2015  200$
02/01/2015  200$
02/01/2015  200$
04/01/2015  200$
05/01/2015  200$
```

I want to know how much I sold in 01 and 03.

How can I select the data?

I am using Entity Framework please give me solution in EF.

```
(from s in _db.SoldProducts 
 where s.SoldDate =< "01/01/2015" and s.SoldDate => 03/01/2015).ToList();
```

something like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be something like:

```
DateTime sd = new DateTime(2015, 1, 1);
DateTime ed = new DateTime(2015, 1, 3);
Decimal s = _db.SoldProducts.Where(s.SoldDate >= sd && s.SoldDate <= ed)
           .Sum(x => x.Amount);
```